# Protractor. How to do a drag and drop action?

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop, protractor

I am currently writing a protractor test and I need to drag a drop some elements... Basically the other developers at the time used angular drag and drop to implement this functionality. I have been searching for a couple of hours but I haven't figured out yet how to get through it. This is the element I am trying to drag. Actually, there are 4 draggable elements and I want to drag the last one on the first one in order to make first the last one:

this.draggableFields = element.all(by.css('dnd-nodrag'));

I using the latest version of protractor and the latest version of webdriverJS as well. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Make a try of this one :

```
  ptor.actions().dragAndDrop(
ptor.findElement(protractor.By.css('dnd-nodrag')).get(0);
ptor.findElement(protractor.By.css('dnd-nodrag')).get(1);
ptor.findElement(protractor.By.css('dnd-nodrag')).get(2);
ptor.findElement(protractor.By.css('dnd-nodrag')).get(3);
    ).perform();
```

Comment: Should I assume ptor = protractor.getInstance(); ? Also, I read that ptor is not used anymore.. on contrary I should use browser.. Is that correct ? I am a bit confused but everything was going well till I bumped into this dragAndDrop action, which is such a pain in the neck :(

Comment: actually i didn't try this before it's just a suggestion for you, yes i mean `ptor = protractor.getInstance();`  but try to do the same logic without doing this ptor if you want ...

Comment: It didn't work by the way :( It's weird though .. I thought it was easier

Comment: Me too, i thought it was easier !